# Alias for sublocations in nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server, web-services

I have a webservice using the following routes in nginx:

```
/my/myservice/backend
/my/myservice/frontend
```

In addtion, I want the two urls

```
/my/myservice
/my/myname
```

to be aliases or redirects to `/my/myservice/frontend`
ow can I configure nginx to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like? Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your server block you want something like this:

```
location /my/myservice { 
    return 301 $scheme://$http_host/my/service/frontend;
}

location /my/myname { 
    return 301 $scheme://$http_host/my/service/frontend;
}
```